# Magento 2.3.4 - How to set the countries allowed by store view?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

On Magento 2.3.4, i am trying to configure the countries allowed by store views but nothing seems to work.

[image]

You can see that I have only configured the USA. But after clearing the cache, the list of countries doesn't seem to update on the frontend.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I applied the changes in the data base:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = 'general/country/allow'
```